# "dspace" How to make my dspace institutional repository on public internet?

Tags: dspace

I have developed an **Institutional Repository using Dspace** and I am
running it on the Departmental LAN But now I want to make it live
(accessible) over the web Sir I want to know the steps

1. "How it can be **run over the Internet or world wide web** so that it can be
   reached to wider audiences "
2. Also want to know Is it necessary to take the **membership of Handle.net** for
   making it accessible over the web or
3. "How could I take the membership for handle.net"

Answer (score 0):

To 1, you will need an IP address (ideally also a hostname) that resolves from the outside. You will typically need to talk to your institution's network administrators for this. Depending on your institution's network set-up, you may also need to have ports opened in the firewall. Once you have that, you'll need to change your DSpace settings to use this hostname / IP address in the DSpace hostname, base URL and URL (https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Configuration+Reference#ConfigurationReference-MainDSpaceConfigurations).

To 2, no you do not need Handle.net membership. The advantage of obtaining your own handle prefix is that you get permanent identifiers in your repository that are tied to your institution. But this is by no means mandatory.

To 3, if you want to register with Handle.net, follow the handle-related steps in the DSpace installation instructions. https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-TheHandleServer Basically, you will need to

- register for a prefix http://www.handle.net/service_agreement.html
- pay for your prefix
- run the make-handle-config command as described in the DSpace documentation
- upload the resulting sitebndl.zip file to CNRI
- then you will receive a prefix; set this up in your DSpace configuration